# Unknow test Suite in Allure reports

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, junit, allure

Проект Maven+Junit+Allure. Allure-junit-adaptor 1.5.4. Для повторного запуска упавших тестов использую `surefire.rerunFailingTestCount`. Allure генерирую c помощью command `line`.

После прогона тестов захожу в папку allure results и вижу два testsuite.xml файла, второй файл без `test suite name`. В самом репорте вижу вcе тесты после запуска находятся в `Unknown Test Suite`. Если добавить вручную и сгенерить снова репорт, то все нормально, и `retries list` отображен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.softjourn</groupId>
    <artifactId>adminPexTests</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <url>https://pexcard.com/</url>
    <properties>
        <!--drivers-->
        <selenium-remote-driver.version>3.4.0</selenium-remote-driver.version>
        <selenium-chrome-driver.version>3.4.0</selenium-chrome-driver.version>
        <selenium-ie-driver.version>3.4.0</selenium-ie-driver.version>
        <selenium-edge-driver.version>3.4.0</selenium-edge-driver.version>
        <selenium-safari-driver.version>3.4.0</selenium-safari-driver.version>
        <phantomjsdriver.version>1.3.0</phantomjsdriver.version>
        <htmlunit.driver.version>2.6</htmlunit.driver.version>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
        <!--libraries-->
        <selenide.version>4.4.3</selenide.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <junit-dataprovider.version>1.10.0</junit-dataprovider.version>
        <selenium-api.version>3.4.0</selenium-api.version>
        <allure.version>1.5.4</allure.version>
        <allure-bundle.version>1.5.4</allure-bundle.version>
        <allure-report-data.version>1.5.4</allure-report-data.version>
        <commons-lang3.version>3.4</commons-lang3.version>
        <slf4j-log4j12.version>1.7.12</slf4j-log4j12.version>
        <jul-to-slf4jversion>1.7.21</jul-to-slf4jversion>
        <rest-assured.version>3.0.1</rest-assured.version>
        <poi.version>3.14</poi.version>
        <poi-ooxml.version>3.14</poi-ooxml.version>
        <assertj-core.version>3.6.1</assertj-core.version>
        <lombok.version>1.16.14</lombok.version>
        <guava.version>21.0</guava.version>
        <google.gson.version>2.8.0</google.gson.version>
        <http.client.version>4.5.3</http.client.version>
        <browsermob.proxy.version>2.1.1</browsermob.proxy.version>
        <webdriver.manager.version>1.6.2</webdriver.manager.version>
        <video-recorder-junit.version>1.4</video-recorder-junit.version>
        <!--plugins-->
        <maven-clean-plugin.version>3.0.0</maven-clean-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.20</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <allure-maven-plugin.version>2.8</allure-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-antrun-plugin.version>1.8</maven-antrun-plugin.version>
        <maven-resources-plugin.version>3.0.2</maven-resources-plugin.version>
        <exec-maven-plugin.version>1.2.1</exec-maven-plugin.version>
        <!--surefire settings-->
        <threadCount>1</threadCount>
        <parallelType>classes</parallelType>
        <!--java version-->
        <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
        <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.baev</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-model</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-bundle.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
        <artifactId>allure-junit-adaptor</artifactId>
        <version>${allure.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-report-data</artifactId>
            <version>${allure-report-data.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jul-to-slf4jversion}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>${selenide.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.tngtech.java</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-dataprovider</artifactId>
            <version>${junit-dataprovider.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-remote-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-chrome-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-ie-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-edge-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${phantomjsdriver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium-safari-driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriver</artifactId>
            <version>${htmlunit.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>${commons-lang3.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>${rest-assured.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>${poi.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>${poi-ooxml.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>${assertj-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>${webdriver.manager.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${google.gson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>${http.client.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>${guava.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>browsermob-core</artifactId>
            <version>${browsermob.proxy.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.automation-remarks</groupId>
            <artifactId>video-recorder-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${video-recorder-junit.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-clean-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
                            <directory>${basedir}/allure-report</directory>
                            <directory>${basedir}/build</directory>
                            <directory>${basedir}/video</directory>
                            <directory>${basedir}/*.har</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <showWarnings>false</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>false</showDeprecation>
                    <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <parallel>classes</parallel>
                    <threadCount>${threadCount}</threadCount>
                    <argLine>
                        -Xmx6g
                        -javaagent:${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>ru.yandex.qatools.allure.junit.AllureRunListener</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>cmd</executable>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>/C</argument>
                                <argument>${basedir}\src\main\resources\allure-2.2.0\bin\allure.bat generate -c ${basedir}\target\allure-results -o ${basedir}\target\allure-reports
                                </argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-resources-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-allure-environment</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/allure-results</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources/properties</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>environment.properties</include>
                                        <include>allure.properties</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Приложите к вопросу (кнопка править) содержимое pom файла

Comment: добавил pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло обновление к Allure 2.0-BETA13.
Спасибо @Dmitry Baev, обновил allure-junit example на github.
https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-junit-example